# Latest row for each combination of item and location

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have a table named `IJ` with a datetime column `IJDATE`, and varchar columns `IJLOC` and `IJITEM`. I need the most recent row for each combination of those two columns (and include the other columns, like `IJLCGT`, an integer, for the most recent row). So for example, from this data:

```
IJLOC   IJITEM      IJDATE      IJLCGT
Reno    12X12X12PX  2013-07-29  175705
Reno    12X12X12PX  2013-08-14  125905
```

I want this result (since it is the most recent row for that combination):

```
IJLOC   IJITEM      IJDATE      IJLCGT
Reno    12X12X12PX  2013-08-14  125905
```

I've tried using MAX and grouping the varchar columns, but then I can't include the other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever named your columns needs their knuckles to meet a swiftly moving ruler.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT IJLOC, IJITEM, IJDATE, IJLCGT,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IJITEM, IJLOC ORDER BY IJDATE DESC)
  FROM dbo.IJ
)
SELECT IJLOC, IJITEM, IJDATE, IJLCGT
FROM cte WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: I agree.  I have no power over how the fields are named.

Comment: Now I need to add fields from another table name IB to this data.  The fields would be QOO, QOH, QCM and AVG.  Where in this code would I do my JOIN to that table?

Comment: @tsqln00b please ask a new question.

Comment: This solution does not solve for the time issue.  If there were multiple adjustments on the same date, I am not getting the proper data back for the field IJRBAL.

Comment: @tsqln00b well, since I don't even see a column named `IJRBAL` in the question, I don't know how I can help. Perhaps you should include the real columns in your question, and more sample data and desired results, instead of trying to change the requirements. Again.

Comment: I figured it out.  I apologize.  I'm trying to not get in trouble by giving away too much of my company's info.  I added the IJLCGT to the code...rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IJITEM, IJLOC ORDER BY IJDATE DESC, IJLCGT DESC)

Comment: +1 for pointing out your "column" names are garbage. You should be able to tell what's in a table just by looking an the table name/column name. I have no clue what the hell `IJRBAL` means. Second fields are a place that you grow corn.

Comment: @Zane Idiojunctional Rhythm Bus Arbitration Logic... duh

Comment: It means Inventory Running Balance.